# Properly applying nonce to a form using AJAX

Tags: functions, javascript, nonce

So I'm still learning around WordPress and can't seem to figure out how to properly hook a nonce into a AJAX Form that I have created.

Here I am hooking and localizing the js file and defining a `update_profile_validation` nonce [**WORKS**]:

```
function enqueue_scripts()
{
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('profile_edit_submit', content_url() . '/mu-plugins/fleishmanhillard/scripts/frontend-profile-edit.js', ['jquery'], '', true);
        wp_localize_script( 'profile_edit_submit', 'profile_edit', [
            // This will generate the admin URL that we can use on the front-end of our website
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            // Pass in a custom nonce name for JS
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('update_profile_validation'),
        ]);
        wp_enqueue_script('profile_edit_submit');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

This method is used to update the user content [**WORKS**]:

```
function ajax_update_profile_post($args)
{
    check_ajax_referer('update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce');
    update_profile_post($args);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_profile_post', 'ajax_update_profile_post' );

function update_profile_post($args  = [])
{
    if (!$args) {
        return;
    }

    // If the server request is POST, proceed to update post
    if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "post") {
        wp_update_post($args);
    }
}
```

Here is my AJAX form submission [**WORKS**]:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function($) {
        $('#profile_update').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : profile_edit.ajaxurl,
                data: $('#profile_update').serialize() +
                    '&my_nonce=' + profile_edit.nonce +
                    '&action=update_profile_post'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the final part of my form:

```
<?php if ($profile->get_edit_post_link()):

    // Set the post field content field
    $post_content = $_POST['content'];

    ajax_update_profile_post([
        'ID' => $profile->get_id(),
        'post_content' => $post_content,
    ]);

    ?>
    <form action="" id="profile_update" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="content" id="post_content">
        <button type="submit"><?= 'Update Post' ?></button>
        <?php wp_nonce_field('update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce'); ?>
    </form>
<?php endif;
```

So the form works and the field submits and all, but I'm having a difficult time understanding how to apply a proper nonce to the form.. All assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to send the nonce along with your AJAX data:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : profile_edit.ajaxurl,
    data: $('#profile_update').serialize() +
        '&my_nonce=' + profile_edit.nonce +
        '&action=update_profile_post', // don't forget the action name!
});
```

Alternatively, since you're using jQuery's `serialize()` function, you could just add the nonce directly in the form:

```php
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce' ); ?>
```

Then since you're doing AJAX, you'd use `check_ajax_referer()` to verify the submitted nonce:

```php
function update_profile_post() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce' );
    // ... the rest of your code.
    wp_die();
}
```

Check the WordPress developer site [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/#example) for more details.

Additionally, I'd use two functions instead of calling the same `update_profile_post()` from the form and the AJAX callback. Something like this would do:

```php
function ajax_update_profile_post() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce' );

    // call update_profile_post() with submitted parameters
    // or call wp_update_post() directly

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_profile_post', 'ajax_update_profile_post' );

function update_profile_post( $args ) {
    // call wp_update_post( $args ) here
    // or just call wp_update_post() directly in your form
}
```

Also, the REST API offers a more structured and predictable way to interact with your site, so you should consider using the API to handle your AJAX actions. In fact, there's an existing endpoint for [updating a post](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post). :)

### UPDATE

1. If you haven't, check out the AJAX guide on the WordPress' [plugin handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/). You'll get more information there that I didn't include in this answer. :)
2. About that `// don't forget the action name!`, it just means that you need to send the [action *name*](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#ajax-action) along with the AJAX data so that WordPress knows which function should be called, which is the above `ajax_update_profile_post()` or the `update_profile_post()` as in the question. And if you didn't send the action name, then you'd likely get the famous `400 Bad Request` error with the output `0` (which is why the REST API is better since it can tell you the exact error).

   And by action name, I'm referring to the `<action>` part as in `wp_ajax_<action>`, which in the question is `update_profile_post`.
3. "*Are we missing a `wp_ajax_no_priv` action?*" — Yes, if you're allowing non-authenticated users (or those who're not logged in) to use the form.

Comment: Wow, @Sally CJ thanks so much! I'm running into a small issue, looks like the `check_ajax_referer( 'update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce');` is throwing a -1 output and hiding the form.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I meant `profile_edit.nonce` and not `profile_edit.update_profile_validation`. I'll correct it in the answer, in 10 mins or so.

Comment: thanks so much! On this part `don't forget the action name!` am I missing anything or is the action name already included? Do I have to call a `action: "lorem ipsum"` inside the ajax request?

Comment: I've updated the whole code with your answer above but for some odd reason all that I'm seeing is a -1 instead of a input box and submit button.

Comment: I'm editing the answer, but from what I could tell, you changed the *nonce action* from `update_profile_validation` to `update_profile_post` - `wp_create_nonce( 'update_profile_post' )`. So could you please roll back the edit because that would invalidate my answer. Or (later) append your updates at the bottom, not changing the original texts.

Comment: thanks again for the guidance! I adjusted the code back, but for some reason it's still showing a -1, as soon as I comment out `check_ajax_referer('update_profile_validation', 'my_nonce');` the input box shows right back up.

Are we missing a `wp_ajax_no_priv` action?

In the ajax call, is the `'&action=update_profile_post'` correct?

Comment: I've revised the answer, but I basically just added additional notes (and corrected the `profile_edit.update_profile_validation` typo). However, the notes should help you get the answers to the questions you asked in the comments, particularly the link in note #1 in the "UPDATE" part. So check that link if you haven't already done so? :)